# Import DB content from package.json command in a Meteor project?

Tags: meteor

I have a snippet to insert an item in my database in my Meteor project. If I run `meteor mongo` on the command line and then past the following code it works.

```
db.groups.insert({
  name: 'Gaming',
  keywords: ['computer games'],
  desc: 'Nunquam vitare lapsus.Hercle, orexis talis!, detrius!',
  img: 'gamers.jpg',
});
```

How can I run this from my package.json file? Is something like this on the right track?

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "importGroups": "meteor mongo ./scripts/addGroupToDb.js"
  },
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason you do not want to use ```Meteor.startup()``` for this?

Comment: Wont that create duplicate groups when I restart my app?

Comment: if the group exists, then don't insert? OR remove the specific doc and re-insert on each run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a startup function that does this job for you:

**/server/lib/startup.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

    if(!groups.findOne()){ // check for the exact doc by providing more fields to the findOne
     groups.insert({
          name: 'Gaming',
          keywords: ['computer games'],
          desc: 'Nunquam vitare lapsus.Hercle, orexis talis!, detrius!',
          img: 'gamers.jpg',
    });
   }
});
```